# Make target with optional wildcard dependency doesn't update when dependency does

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using a makefile to build some documents from markdown. Since I have various possible outputs, I'm using a pattern rule. And since the input documents may or may not have associated tables, they have a wildcard dependency for csv files with the same stem filename:

```
tables = $(wildcard $*_*.csv)

%.docx: %.md $(tables)
    @echo building $@
    @touch $@
```

This works fine the first time:

```
$ touch thing.md
$ touch thing_table.csv
$ make thing.docx
building thing.docx
$ ls thing.docx
thing.docx
```

However, if the table file is updated, make still thinks everything's up to date:

```
$ touch thing_table.csv
$ make thing.docx
make: `thing.docx' is up to date.
```

I think this must have something to do with the order in which make evaluates things, but I don't understand it well enough to figure out how to make this work.

I can do sort of what I want to do using a more "literal" pattern rule:

```
%.docx: %.md %_*.csv
    @echo building $@
    @touch $@
```

But of course this fails in the absence of appropriately-named csv files:

```
$ rm thing.docx thing_table.csv
$ make thing.docx
make: *** No rule to make target `thing.docx'.  Stop.
```

Is there a way to specify a target dependency such that if a target is foo.docx the dependencies would be foo_*.csv, but have those dependencies be optional (i.e. the target still works if the files don't exist) AND have it appropriately update if those optional dependencies change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like secondary expansion will work here:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.docx: %.md $$(wildcard $$*_*.csv)
    @echo building $@
    @touch $@
```